# Using apply/call instead of bind on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've been working with asynchronous functions

I've finally got around to avoid `var _this = this;` and switched to actually using `call/apply`. However when doing this,

```
/* inside instantiated obj */
setTimeout(function(){ 
  /* more code here */ 
}.apply(this), 0);
```

,does not launch an error and seems to work. Why? Because I recently noticed that it was "wrong" and should actually be:

```
/* inside instantiated obj */
setTimeout(function(){ 
  /* more code here */ 
}.bind(this), 0);
```

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `apply` or `call` methods on a function object, *they will be invoked immediately* and only the result is passed to the `setTimeout`.

But `bind` returns a new function object and that will be invoked after the timeout elapses.

Since the timeout is set to 0, both the `setTimeout`s wait only 0 milliseconds and so you don't see any difference.

---

You can use this example to understand it better.

```
console.log(new Date());

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Apply", new Date());
}.apply(this), 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Bind", new Date());
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

You should be able to observe 3 seconds difference between `Bind`'s and the other two.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So if I understand correctly with apply/call it's not asynchronous anymore?

Comment: @Grimbode When you use `apply/call` they are triggered straight away.

Comment: So the function I actually want to be handled in an asynchronous way just gets invoked immediately and the setTimeout only handles the result?

Comment: @Grimbode Yes, exactly.